# Comparing calculated real numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, lengths, etoolbox

"\ifdimless" can compare two real numbers. But, how can we feed the result of a calculation to this function ?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\begin{document}

% This comparison works well: small versus specified 
\newlength{\SmallLength}
\setlength{\SmallLength}{1.2 pt}
\newlength{\SpecifiedLength}
\setlength{\SpecifiedLength}{3.4 pt}
\ifdimless{\SpecifiedLength}{\SmallLength}{specified smaller}{specified higher}%

% Second is divided by First, and the result works well (\DividedNumbers)
\def\FirstNumber{2.3}
\def\SecondNumber{4.5}
\def\DividedNumbers{\pgfmathparse{div(\SecondNumber,\FirstNumber)}\pgfmathresult}
\DividedNumbers

%\Divided is taken from \DividedNumbers: doesn't work...
\newlength{\DividedLength}
%\setlength{\DividedLength}{\DividedNumbers pt}
%\ifdimless{\DividedLength}{\SmallLength}{divided smaller}{divided higher}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the TiKZ `math` library?

Comment: Yes I had, and it didn't solve the problem. The Answer #2 addresses specifically my issue: "Store the result rather than the calculation"

Comment: The answer of @kpym uses the TIKZ math library, and works well too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the result rather than the calculation:

> specified higher
>   1
>   divided smaller

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\begin{document}

% This comparison works well: small versus specified 
\newlength{\SmallLength}
\setlength{\SmallLength}{1.2 pt}
\newlength{\SpecifiedLength}
\setlength{\SpecifiedLength}{3.4 pt}
\ifdimless{\SpecifiedLength}{\SmallLength}{specified smaller}{specified higher}%

% Second is divided by First, and the result works well (\DividedNumbers)
\def\FirstNumber{2.3}
\def\SecondNumber{4.5}
\pgfmathparse{div(\SecondNumber,\FirstNumber)}
\edef\DividedNumbers{\pgfmathresult}% Store result in \DividedNumbers
\DividedNumbers

% \Divided is taken from \DividedNumbers:
\newlength{\DividedLength}
\setlength{\DividedLength}{\DividedNumbers pt}
\ifdimless{\DividedLength}{\SmallLength}{divided smaller}{divided higher}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or you can use `\pgfmathsetlength{\DividedLength}{div(\SecondNumber,\FirstNumber)}`.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you a more powerful approach, where computations can be directly input. The `interface3.pdf` manual of `expl3` will tell you the syntax for the “dimension expressions” in the arguments to `\xifdimless` and the “floating point expressions” in the argument to `\eval`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifdimless}{mmmm}
 {
  \dim_compare:nTF { #1 < #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\eval}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% This comparison works well: small versus specified 
\newlength{\SmallLength}
\setlength{\SmallLength}{1.2pt}
\newlength{\SpecifiedLength}
\setlength{\SpecifiedLength}{3.4pt}

% first test A
\xifdimless{\SpecifiedLength}{\SmallLength}{specified smaller}{specified higher}

% first test B
\xifdimless{1.2pt+2.2pt}{4pt-2.8pt}{specified smaller}{specified higher}

% second test
\xifdimless{\SmallLength}{\SpecifiedLength}{specified smaller}{specified higher}

% third test
\xifdimless{ \eval{4.5/2.3} pt }{\SmallLength}{divided smaller}{divided higher}

% fourth test
\xifdimless{ \eval{2.3/4.5} pt }{\SmallLength}{divided smaller}{divided higher}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, a much more powerful approach: wow ! Grazie !

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @cfr in the comment you can use `tikzmath` to achieve this:

```
\documentclass[preview, border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\SmallLength}
\setlength{\SmallLength}{1.2 pt}

\tikzmath{
  if 4.5/2.3 < \SmallLength  then {
    {divided smaller};
  } else {
    {divided higher or equal};
  };
}

\end{document}
```

[image]